# overloading << operators and inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators, polymorphism

I've got a base class and then several derived classes. I would like to overload the "<<" operator for these derived classes. For normal operators, i.e. '+', virtual functions do the trick. What I understand to be the standard convention is to declare

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, MyClass& A);
```

within my class and then define the function after the class. A priori I would think adding virtual to the above definition would make it work, but after some thought (and errors from my compiler) I realize that doesn't make much sense.

I tried a different tack on a test case, where all the class members are public. For example:

```
class Foo{
 //bla
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Foo& foo){
  cout << "Foo" << endl;
  return foo;
}

class Bar : public Foo{
 //bla
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Bar& bar){
  cout << "Bar" << endl;
  return bar;
}

///////////////////////

Bar bar = Bar();
cout << bar << endl; // outputs 'Foo', not 'Bar'
```

So in some way this is "polymorphism gone bad" -- the base class operator<< is being called rather than the derived class operator. In the above example, how do I make the correct operator get called for the derived class? And more generally, if my class has private members I want to protect, how can I correct the operator overloading while using the friend keyword?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a virtual helper function. Here's a completely untested example, so excuse any syntax mistakes:

```
virtual ostream& Foo::print(ostream& out) const {
    return out << "Foo";
}

virtual ostream& Bar::print(ostream& out) const {
    return out << "Bar";
}

// If print is public, this doesn't need to be a friend.
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Foo& foo) {
    return foo.print(out);
}
```

**Edit:** Cleaned up per @Omnifarious suggestions.

Comment: I think this has two flaws. One flaw is a huge flaw, and the other is a minor flaw. Huge flaw first... you should never invisibly put in `endl`. `endl` forces a stream flush, which can be a big performance problem in some circumstances. Use `'\n'`. It's guaranteed to be just as portable (in fact, `endl` is defined in terms of outputting `'\n'`, and doesn't incur a flush overhead. Secondly, I would do this: `return out << "Foo\n";`. Feels slightly cleaner. It conceptually turns the whole thing into a long chain of `<<` operations.

Comment: @Omnifarious I would never put `endl` in a `operator<<` overload. I was just following the OP's code.

Comment: As an aside, I think it was a mistake to have ever put the `endl` IOStream manipulator in the language at all. There is already a `flush` manipulator, and the `endl` manipulator conflates two operations that should always be distinct.

Comment: @Omnifarious Interesting, I didn't even know that existed.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you just create a polymorphic `print` method in the base class which is called by a single free friend function.

Comment: If print is public, then we can ditch the friend.

Answer (score 1):

Make `operator<<` a free function that forwards the call to a `virtual` method of class `Foo`.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/hbegs)**.

Answer (score 1):

With the proper code corrections in place, your **code works fine; nothing to be done**:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Foo& foo) {
  out << "Foo" << endl;  // 'out' and not 'cout'
  return out;  // returns 'out' and not 'foo'
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Bar& bar) {
  out << "Bar" << endl;  // 'out' and not 'cout'
  return out;  // returns 'out' and not 'bar'
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/f8Biv). For accessing `private` members, you can make this function as `friend` in the desired `class`.

Comment: Intriguing. In my actually code I had used out correctly instead of cout, but it still didn't work. There must be something subtle going on the isn't captured by the filler //bla classes.