# Overloaded output operator in base class

Tags: c++

I have a number of classes that represent various computer components, each of which have an overloaded `<<` operator declared as follows:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const MotherBoard& mb);
```

Each returns an ostream object with a unique stream describing that component, some of which are composed of other components. I decided to create a base class called `Component` in order to generate a unique id as well as some other functions that all the components will publicly derive. Of course, the overloaded `<<` operator doesn't work with pointers to `Component` objects.

I was wondering how I would effect something like a pure virtual function that will be overwritten by each derived class's `<<` operator so I could do something like:

```
Component* mobo = new MotherBoard();

cout << *mobo << endl;

delete mobo;
```

Also related to: [overloading << operators and inherited classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690807/overloading-operators-and-inherited-classes?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Component 
{
public:
    // Constructor, destructor and other stuff

    virtual std::ostream &output(std::ostream &os) const
        { os << "Generic component\n"; return os; }
};

class MotherBoard : public Component
{
public:
    // Constructor, destructor and other stuff

    virtual std::ostream &output(std::ostream &os) const
        { os << "Motherboard\n"; return os; }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Component &component)
{
    return component.output(os);
}

int main()
{
    MotherBoard mb; 
    Component &component = mb;

    std::cout << component;
}
```

Comment: +1 I have actually seen this a couple of times and it makes sense. But, given that `output` is public, `operator<<` need not be a friend (and shouldn't). Also, in the past I have seen the signature as: `virtual std::ostream& print( std::ostream& out ) const;` so that it could be chained if called manually: `myobj.output( std::cout ) << std::endl;` I don't quite like the syntax though.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas You're right, the friend declaration isn't needed, just a force of habit I guess. :) Updated code as per your suggestions.